# Reading and setting LE 2M PHY on Bluetooth v5.0

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hci, web-bluetooth, bleno

Need to determine whether the central and peripheral devices (both running Bluetooth 5.0) are communicating via the faster LE 2M PHY bit rate.

The command I am sending via the `hcitool`:

`sudo hcitool cmd 8 30 40 0`

The response received:

`01 30 20 01`

The `btmon` output:

```
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22                                     {0x0005} 3503.199467
@ RAW Close: hcitool                                                              {0x0005} 3503.199506
@ RAW Open: hcitool (privileged) version 2.22                              {0x0005} [hci0] 3503.199594
< HCI Command: LE Read PHY (0x08|0x0030) plen 2                              #11120 [hci0] 3503.200023
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                  #11121 [hci0] 3503.200353
      LE Read PHY (0x08|0x0030) ncmd 1
        Status: Unknown HCI Command (0x01)
@ RAW Close: hcitool
```

For some reason I am getting the `Unknown HCI Command` error when running this command on the RPi 4 which is set as the peripheral via bleno.

Am I doing something wrong? Are there preliminary steps I need to take before I can read and set the symbol rate?

More info:

```
< HCI Command: Read Local Ve.. (0x04|0x0001) plen 0  #3 [hci0] 42.465863
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 12         #4 [hci0] 42.466325
      Read Local Version Information (0x04|0x0001) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        HCI version: Bluetooth 5.0 (0x09) - Revision 315 (0x013b)
        LMP version: Bluetooth 5.0 (0x09) - Subversion 24857 (0x6119)
        Manufacturer: Cypress Semiconductor Corporation (305)
@ RAW Close: hcitool                           {0x0003} [hci0] 42.466507
```

Comment: Is there a Web Bluetooth aspect to this question?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the miscommunication, Web Bluetooth is acting as the central. It appears as though the RPi 4 does not support LE 2M PHY or any of the optional Bluetooth 5 features. Could that be why I am getting the unknown error?